# Which VPN setup is iOS/Mac friendly and easy?

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, macports, ios

Normally my choice for VPN is OpenVPN which I have successfully setup before. However on iOS that is not a choice. I only see L2TP, PPTP and IPSec so I guess that I will have to learn a new way to setup a VPN.

None of those options is listed in Macports, hence I guess it is just a matter of more custom hacks.

I would like to know which one of those alternatives is easier to install on a Mac (as a server). Just for personal use, hence the most basic setup would be enough.

NOTE: Normally I avoid the trouble of setting up a VPN server and use a ssh tunnel for the server/port I want. But that seems out of question on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you know OpenVPN, I would use [tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/)  It's a GUI and service wrapper for OpenVPN that I find works very well, but requites editing OpenVPN config files by hand.  That doesn't seem to be a disadvantage in your case though.

Comment: thanks! I already use tunnelblick and I know OpenVPN quite well. That is my current setup to access my home server. However and like I wrote in my question, Mac and iOS support L2TP / PPTP / IPSec out of the box, and it seems that OpenVPN clients for iOS must run on jailbroken devices. That's out of question if I want to preserve my Apple developer account. I would like to setup one of the supported by default protocols, but I do not know which one has a good opensource implementation with good support for a Mac server.

Comment: Ah.  I misread your question.  I read your question as saying you'd used OpenVPN with other OSes, but never MacOS.  Sadly, that is also the only one I have used too.